# How to get the BUILD USER details in slack from jenkins when user trigger the job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, slack

Iam working on slack integration and i have configured the slack as follows.

```
    post {
    success {
        slackSend color: "good", message:"Build deployed successfully - ${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"
            }
    failure {
        slackSend color: 'danger', failOnError: true, message: 'Build failed  - ${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)'
            }
    aborted {
        slackSend color: 'warning', message: 'Build aborted for idesigner-react-qa'
            }
```

But I need to add which user has started the build here as developers are triggering the build.
Can someone help me for this???

Note : My O/P is attached here :

> Build deployed successfully - idesigner-react-qa 25 (Open)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data as shown below and embed that in the slack message.

```
def userCause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')[0]
echo userCause.getString("userName") //Prints Username
echo userCause.getString("userId") // Prints User ID
```

After extracting the Usercause you will have the following information.

```json
[
  { 
    "_class\": "hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause",
    "shortDescription": "Started by user something",
    "userId": "something",
    "userName": "something"
  }
]
```